# IntelliJ: Replace method call with body

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods, refactoring, jetbrains-ide

Is there a refactoring in IntelliJ where I can replace the call of a method with the body of the method. For example:

```
static int doubleValue(int x) {
    return 2 * x;
}

System.out.println(doubleValue(3));
```

becomes

```
 System.out.println(2 * 3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, please use "Refactor | Inline Method"

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple, didn't find it somehow.